# Dplyr difference between select and group_by with respect to quoted variables?

Tags: r, dplyr

In the current version of dplyr, `select` arguments can be passed by value:

```
variable <- "Species"
iris %>% 
    select(variable)

#       Species
#1       setosa
#2       setosa
#3       setosa
#4       setosa
#5       setosa
#6       setosa
#...
```

But `group_by` arguments cannot be passed by value:

```
iris %>% 
    group_by(variable) %>% 
    summarise(Petal.Length = mean(Petal.Length))

# Error in grouped_df_impl(data, unname(vars), drop) : 
# Column `variable` is unknown
```

The [documented dplyr::select behaviour](https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/dplyr/versions/0.7.2/topics/select) is

```
iris %>% select(Species)
```

And the documented [documented dplyr::group_by behaviour](https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/dplyr/versions/0.7.2/topics/group_by) is

```
iris %>% 
    group_by(Species) %>% 
    summarise(Petal.Length = mean(Petal.Length))
```

- Why are `select` and `group_by` different with respect to passing arguments by value?
- Why is the first `select` call working and will it continue to work in the future?
- Why is the first `group_by` call not working? I'm trying to figure out what combination of `quo()`, `enquo()` and `!!` I should use to make it work.

I need this because I would like to create a function that takes a grouping variable as input parameter, if possible the grouping variable should be given as a character string, because two other function parameters are already given as character strings.

Comment: Isn't this part of the effort to [use tidy evaluation semantics instead of standard evaluation](http://dplyr.tidyverse.org/reference/se-deprecated.html)?

Comment: In `browseVignettes(package = "dplyr")`, you'll find one on programming, which covers what is/will be idiomatic, anyways.

Comment: I read the [dplyr vignette on programming](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/dplyr/vignettes/programming.html) a few days ago, now reading the [rlang vignette on tidy evaluation](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/rlang/vignettes/tidy-evaluation.html).

Comment: `group_by(get(variable))` should get it to work but not sure why `select` and `group_by` are different in this respect.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

To pass string as symbol or unevaluated code, you have to first parse it to symbol or quosure. You can use `sym` or `parse_expr` from `rlang` to parse and later use `!!` to unquote:

```
library(dplyr)

variable <- rlang::sym("Species")
# variable <- rlang::parse_expr("Species")

iris %>% 
  group_by(!! variable) %>% 
  summarise(Petal.Length = mean(Petal.Length))
```

`!!` is a shortcut for `UQ()`, which unquotes the expression or symbol. This allows `variable` to be evaluated only within the scope of where it is called, namely, `group_by`.

**Difference between `sym` and `parse_expr` and which one to use when?**

The short answer: it doesn't matter in this case.

The long answer:

A symbol is a way to refer to an R object, basically the "name" of an object. So `sym` is similar to `as.name` in base R. `parse_expr` on the other hand transforms some text into R expressions. This is similar to `parse` in base R.

Expressions can be *any* R code, not *just* code that references R objects. So you can parse the *code* that references an R object, but you can't turn some random code into `sym` if the object that it references does not exist.

In general, you will use `sym` when your string refers to an object (although `parse_expr` would also work), and use `parse_expr` when you are trying to parse *any* other R code for further evaluation.

For this particular use case, `variable` is supposed to be referencing an object, so turning it into a `sym` would work. On the other hand, parsing it as an expression would also work because that is the *code* that is going to be evaluated inside `group_by` when being unquoted by `!!`.

Comment: Thanks, using `rlang::sym` and `!!` I can pass the grouping variable as a character string.

Comment: It took me a while to understand why `!!` is necessary. The [rlang vignette on tidy evaluation](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/rlang/vignettes/tidy-evaluation.html) gives an example that helped me understand: "[...]with quasiquotation: users can bypass symbolic evaluation completely by unquoting values. For instance, the following expressions are completely equivalent: # Taking an expression: `dplyr::mutate(mtcars, cyl2 = cyl * 2)` # Taking a value: `var <- mtcars$cyl * 2`; `dplyr::mutate(mtcars, cyl2 = !! var)"`."

Comment: Thanks for the explanation. Do you know what the differences between `sym` and `parse_expr` is? Why should I prefer one to the other?

Comment: @tmastny Added an explanation of the difference between the two. Hope this helps