# What is the difference between sym() and parse_expr() in the rlang package?

Tags: r, string, evaluation, rlang

Using the rlang package, I wonder what is the difference between `sym()` and `parse_expr()`. Consider for example the following expressions:

```
ex1 = sym('a')
ex2 = parse_expr('a')
```

They both return

```
a

identical(ex1, ex2)
[1] TRUE
```

Suppose now I need a quosure:

```
ex3 = quo(!!sym('a'))
ex4 = quo(!!parse_expr('a'))
```

In both case, the result is:

```
<quosure>
expr: ^a
env:  global

identical(ex3, ex4)
[1] TRUE
```

However, the two following are not the same for some reasons.

```
ex5 = quo(!!sym('a - b'))
ex6 = quo(!!parse_expr('a - b'))
```

Apparently they are identical as both return:

```
<quosure>
expr: ^a - b
env:  global
```

Yet,

```
identical(ex5, ex6)
[1] FALSE
```

So, my question is, what are the differences between `sym()` and `parse_expr()`?
What does one do that the other cannot? And why is `ex5` apparently similar to `ex6`, but `identical(ex5, ex6)` returns FALSE?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Referencing my answer to this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45678466/dplyr-difference-between-select-and-group-by-with-respect-to-quoted-variables/47226350#47226350):

A symbol is a way to refer to an R object, basically the "name" of an object. So `sym` is similar to `as.name` in base R. `parse_expr` on the other hand transforms some text into R expressions. This is similar to `parse` in base R.

Expressions can be any R code, not just code that references R objects. So you can parse the code that references an R object, but you can't turn some random code into `sym` if the object that the code references does not exist.

In general, you will use `sym` when your string refers to an object (although `parse_expr` would also work), and use `parse_expr` when you are trying to parse any other R code for further evaluation.

For your first example, `a` can be both a name that references an object AND an expression, so turning it into either a `sym` or `parse_expr` would practically mean the same thing. In fact, R implicitly converts the expression to a `sym` when it can, as shown in your first example.

For your last example however, `a - b` is really intended to be an expression (unless you have an R object that is weirdly named `a - b`). By printing the following, you will see that using `sym` vs `parse_expr` for R code *that is intended to be an expression, not an R object* produces two different results:

```
> quo(!!sym('a - b'))
<quosure: global>
~`a - b`

> quo(!!parse_expr('a-b'))
<quosure: global>
~a - b
```

Here, `sym` turns `a - b` into a *name/symbol* of an object, hence the back ticks around `a - b`, while `parse_expr` turns it into an expression as expected.

Answer (score 4):

To augment the previous answer, note that `ex5` and `ex6` are not in fact identical.

```
a <- 5
b <- 3
eval_tidy(ex6)
# [1] 2
eval_tidy(ex5)
# Error in eval_tidy(ex5) : object 'a - b' not found
`a - b` <- pi
eval_tidy(ex5)
# [1] 3.141593
```