# Using strings as arguments in custom dplyr function using non-standard evaluation

Tags: r, dplyr, nse

I'm trying to write a function that takes a metric and computes relative difference from the first value of that metric with dplyr functions and non-standard evaluation. Following these instructions (https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/dplyr/vignettes/programming.html), I've come up with this, which works well:

```
testFun <- function(data, metric) {
  metric <- enquo(metric)
  metric_name <- quo_name(metric)
  data %>%
    mutate(!!metric_name := `-`(!!metric, first(!!metric)) / first(!!metric) * 
100)
}

testFun(data.frame(x = c("a", "b", "c"), y = 1:3), y)
```

However, the problem is that elsewhere in the code I have other functions that take the metric name as a string stored in some variable, for example:

```
myVar <- "y"
```

I wouldn't want to change everything, but I'd still like to use the same variables. So my question is, can I make the same function work with this call?

```
testFun(data.frame(x = c("a", "b", "c"), y = 1:3), myVar)
```

Either by changing something in the function or adapting the input in the call somehow. The latter would be preferable. I've tried various quoting, unquoting, evaluation etc. of myVar, but I don't really understand all of this that well and couldn't come up with a working solution. The way I understand it, I somehow need to get ~y from myVar. Can it be done?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can either use `sym` to turn "y" into a symbol or `parse_expr` to parse it into an expression, then unquote it using `!!`:

```
library(rlang)

testFun(data.frame(x = c("a", "b", "c"), y = 1:3), !!sym(myVar))

testFun(data.frame(x = c("a", "b", "c"), y = 1:3), !!parse_expr(myVar))
```

**Result:**

```
  x   y
1 a   0
2 b 100
3 c 200
```

Check my answer in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50158884/what-is-the-difference-between-sym-and-parse-expr-in-the-rlang-package/50161301#50161301) for explanation of difference between `sym` and `parse_expr`.

Comment: Amazing, that does the job! Thanks so much! :)