# How to evaluate a string as a variable in R?

Tags: r, paste

Perhaps is a silly question, but I couldn't find a solution for this.
I want to pass the variable name using `paste()`, and use the variable name to evaluate an inequality within `dplyr::filter()`, but it returns 0 rows, not my expected output

I tried using `eval()` and `as.formula()` without success

```
library(dplyr)

dcl <- '07'
xdecil <- paste('detr0', dcl, sep='')
final_cust <- cd_probs %>% filter(final_prob>=xdecil)
```

Comment: `xdecil` returns `"detr007"`, so how are you expecting to compare `final_prob` (likely a numeric variable) with a string? Are you trying to do string comparison?

Comment: Please give a [mcve]. See [How to make a great R reproducible example?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/5963269/4996248) for what this would mean in R.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We can turn the string representation of the variable name to a symbol and unquote with `!!`:

```
library(dplyr)
library(rlang)

varname <- 'mpg'
mtcars %>%
  filter(qsec >= !!sym(varname))
```

or with `as.name` if we don't want to load `rlang`:

```
library(dplyr)

varname <- 'mpg'
mtcars %>%
  filter(qsec >= !!as.name(varname))
```

**Output:**

```
    mpg cyl  disp  hp drat    wt  qsec vs am gear carb
1  18.1   6 225.0 105 2.76 3.460 20.22  1  0    3    1
2  14.3   8 360.0 245 3.21 3.570 15.84  0  0    3    4
3  22.8   4 140.8  95 3.92 3.150 22.90  1  0    4    2
4  17.8   6 167.6 123 3.92 3.440 18.90  1  0    4    4
5  16.4   8 275.8 180 3.07 4.070 17.40  0  0    3    3
6  17.3   8 275.8 180 3.07 3.730 17.60  0  0    3    3
7  15.2   8 275.8 180 3.07 3.780 18.00  0  0    3    3
8  10.4   8 472.0 205 2.93 5.250 17.98  0  0    3    4
9  10.4   8 460.0 215 3.00 5.424 17.82  0  0    3    4
10 14.7   8 440.0 230 3.23 5.345 17.42  0  0    3    4
11 15.5   8 318.0 150 2.76 3.520 16.87  0  0    3    2
12 15.2   8 304.0 150 3.15 3.435 17.30  0  0    3    2
13 13.3   8 350.0 245 3.73 3.840 15.41  0  0    3    4
```

Comment: I wish I could upvote this ten times. Googling for this issue is hard, and I don't know how I would've found the `as.name`. It's not in https://dplyr.tidyverse.org/articles/programming.html#different-expressions, where I look for this stuff.

Comment: @dfrankow Related and may give you some insights: https://stackoverflow.com/a/50161301/5150629

Answer (score 0):

Although I agree with @avid_useR solution, I share some of my thoughts:

If I understand your issue correctly, you want the `xdecil` object to point to another existing variable named `detro007` with certain value? If that is the case, you can use `?get()` function to assign the value of your existing `detro007` variable to the one you created.

Try:

```
library(dplyr)

dcl <- '07'
xdecil <- get(paste('detr0', dcl, sep=''))

final_cust <- cd_probs %>% filter(final_prob>=xdecil)
```